# HTML - Refresh form fields - different behavior in IE and Phone-android

Tags: javascript, android, html

I have a form with a list box and several text boxes (input tags). When a user selects an item in the listbox I prepopulate the text in the text boxes. This is done in a function that executes in the listbox's onclick event.
In IE running on the desktop everything runs as expected. On the browser running on an android phone here is what happens:
1 - first selection - text boxes remain blank
2 - next selection - text boxes get populated with the previous selection
3 - any further selection populates the text boxes with the previous selection.

Why the difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed now. I replaced the onclick event on the list box with onchange and it works as expected on all browsers I tried.